# ¿Porque solo se ejecuta una vez mi consulta la hora de recorrer una tabla? php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy armando una pagina que administra alumnos y sus asistencias, ambos asociados por una id idéntica. Mi lógica seria recorrer la primera tabla (alumnos) como un vector y luego recorrer la segunda tabla. Con el id obtenido de alumnos + el id obtenido de asistencias, hacer un if para confirmar si las asistencias pertenece al alumno, recorriendo varias veces y mostrando el contenido. Pero mi problema viene que el recorrido de asistencias solo se hace 1 vez solo con el primer alumno, no con los demás

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
} else {
?>
<div class="container">
    <?php
    $que = "SELECT * FROM datos_a";
    $quer = "SELECT * FROM asistencia";
    $re2 = mysqli_query($con, $quer);

    $re = mysqli_query($con, $que);
    include("include/buscador3.php");
    if (isset($result)) {
        $re = $result;
    }
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($re)) {  //agarro 1 alumno
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($re2)){  //recorro asistencias
        if ($row['id_alumno'] == $row2['id_a_asis']) {  
        //compruebo si idA es igual a idAs
        ?>
            <div class="row mod1">
                <div class="col-3 badge border border-dark">
                    <?php echo $row['nombre'] . " " . $row['apellido']; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 badge border border-dark">
                    <?php echo $row['escuela']; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 badge border border-dark">
                    <?php echo $row['grado']; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 badge border border-dark">
                    <?php echo $row2['asis_tipo']; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
     }
   }
}
?>
```

Si pongo un echo debajo del primer while para fijarme si esta leyendo los alumnos, si lo hace (si  recorre) luego en el 2do while si pongo un echo, me aparecen las veces que se ejecuta. Pero luego de la 1ra vez que se ejecuto el 2do while, no vuelve a ejecutarse mas. el 1er while sigue hasta que se termine el vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tu problema radica en que **id_a_asis** es el indice de la segunda tabla y no su clave Foranea (FK), los indices siempre coincidirán en el primer registro y dos WHILE también es poco eficiente, el resultado de la consulta lo resuelve **MySQL** sin problemas al ejecutar una consulta con un **LEFT JOIN**

ej:

```
SELECT d.* FROM datos_a d LEFT JOIN ON asistencia a ON d.id_alumno=a.id_alumno;
```

o:

```
SELECT a.* FROM asistencia a LEFT JOIN ON asistencia a ON d.id_alumno=a.id_alumno;
```

Donde **a.id_alumno** es al clave foránea, esta es una columna que establece la relación lógica entre las tablas donde almacenas los datos del alumno y la tabla en donde almacenas las asistencias.

Comment: ¡¡¡Muchas gracias¡¡¡ ya esta andando, al final use el INNER JOIN que me simplifico todo